# Backbone: swap out elements without ruining table

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, hidden

I have an input form on the left of the page, and when you input some data it fills the right half of the page with user data.

I'd like to be able to click on a `<td>` element on any of the users and have that `<td>` be hidden as a text box appears. The idea is to be able to click on an element and then all of the sudden you can edit it. I'm stuck at the first step- hiding the existing element.

The idea is that if there's two `<td>` elements occupying the 2nd and 3rd position in any given row, and one of them is hidden and the other's visible then a swap between will appear like the same position is just changing elements.

p1.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>User List</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" defer></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./node_modules/backbone/node_modules/underscore/underscore-min.js" defer></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./node_modules/backbone/backbone-min.js" defer></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="p1.js" defer></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" defer>
</head>
<body>
<br>

<div id="appView" class="container">
  <!-- INPUTS -->
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label>First Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputFirst" placeholder="Enter First Name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label>Last Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputLast" placeholder="Enter Last Name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label>Email</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Enter Email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label>Phone Number</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPhone" placeholder="Enter Phone Number">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

  <!-- USER TABLE -->

  <!-- Table -->
  <div class="col-sm-6 users" id="userList">

  </div> <!-- end of col-sm-6 -->
</div> <!-- end appView, container -->


<script type="text/template" id="userTemplate">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <button type="button" class="close delete" data-dismiss="lightbox" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <td>Name:</td>
          <td>
            <div class="nameHide"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"> <%= first %> <%- last %> </span>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="nameEdit" placeholder="New First Name..." hidden>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>Email:</td>
          <td class="emailHide"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"> <%- email %></span></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>Phone:</td>
          <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"> <%- phone %></span></td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</script>
<style>
  .glyphicon .glyphicon-user {
    padding-right: 5px;
  }
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

p1.js:

```
(function($){
  //USER
    var User = Backbone.Model.extend({});

  //USERLIST
  var UserList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: User
  });
  var userList = new UserList;

  //USERVIEW
  var UserView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
      "click .delete": "deleteUser",
      "click .nameHide": "editUser"
    },
    template: _.template($('#userTemplate').html()),

    initialize: function(){
      this.listenTo(this.model, 'destroy', this.remove);
    },

    render: function(){
      this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
      return this;
    },

    deleteUser: function() {
      this.model.destroy();
    },

    //THIS IS THE ONE I HAVE A QUESTION ABOUT!!!!!
    editUser: function() {
      this.$('nameHide').style.display="none";
      this.$('.nameEdit').style.display="inline";
    }
  });


  //APPVIEW
    var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $('#appView'),
    events: {
      'keypress #inputFirst': 'addUser',
      'keypress #inputLast': 'addUser',
      'keypress #inputEmail': 'addUser',
      'keypress #inputPhone': 'addUser'
    },
        initialize: function(){
      this.inputFirst = this.$('#inputFirst');
      this.inputLast = this.$('#inputLast');
      this.inputEmail = this.$('#inputEmail');
      this.inputPhone = this.$('#inputPhone');
            _.bindAll(this, 'render');
            this.listenTo(userList, 'add', this.pushUser);
        },

        render: function(){
            //$('#userList').append("<li>yo</li>");
        },

    addUser: function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode != 13) return;
      if (!this.inputFirst.val()) return;
      var validEmail = this.isEmailValid(this.inputEmail.val());
      if (!validEmail) return;
      e.preventDefault();
      userList.create({
        first: this.inputFirst.val(),
        last: this.inputLast.val(),
        email: this.inputEmail.val(),
        phone: this.inputPhone.val()
      });
    },

    //checks to see if the email is valid, returns false if not, as in "no, this is not valid"
    isEmailValid: function(email) {
      atPos = email.indexOf("@");
      stopPos = email.lastIndexOf(".");
      stopPosLast = email.indexOf(".");
      if (atPos === -1 || stopPos === -1) return false;
      if (stopPos - atPos <= 1) return false;
      if (atPos == 0) return false;
      if (stopPosLast < 2) return false; //can't put upper bound on domain length because of new TLDs
      return true;
    },

    pushUser: function(user) {
      var userView = new UserView({model: user});
      this.$('#userList').append(userView.render().el);
      this.inputFirst.val("");
      this.inputLast.val("");
      this.inputEmail.val("");
      this.inputPhone.val("");
    }
    });

    var appView = new AppView();

}) (jQuery);
```

Comment: Why try to show/hide `<td>`s when you could show/hide their contents (possibly using internal `<div>`s to separate the pieces) and avoid the whole problem altogether?

Comment: Sure, hiding their contents would work too, but it seems like it's the same problem: showing/hiding a <td> vs. showing/hiding a <div> appears to be the same challenge. Please correct me if I'm wrong; I often am.